# How many characters can fit in a C++ string?

Tags: c++, string, size, storage

I need to store in a variable, kilobytes or even megabytes of plain text, so I want to know how many characters can fit in a standard string (aka `std::string` plus string library).

Comment: Does it need to be in memory all at once?

Comment: You may wish to reconsider the design, std::rope can be more useful for manipulation of large strings, and mmap for efficient handling of strings on disk.

Comment: `std::rope` ? SGI has a rope class, but (the current) C++ doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` has the member function [`max_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) which returns the maximum length of a `std::string` in that implementation.

Comment: do you have any idea why this method is not static? Only reason I can imagine is that an implementation could consider actual memory consumption when calculating the max size, but imho that would be of little use and by far not outweigh the disadvantage of having to create an instance first

Comment: @tobi303 `std::string::max_size` doesn't retrieve a static property - it calls the `max_size()` function of the allocator used for the string, so this can be different based on [`Allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) used. I haven't double-checked, but I believe the default value, if you don't use your own `Allocator`, is [`std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your implementation. Try calling `std::string::max_size()` and find out.